# Get value from another method

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use data that I have placed on the same class but in a different method (I believe that is the terminology) but I cannot seem to access this data for some odd reason. I can do so when I place it all together (in the timer) but that would consume a TONNE of memory would it not since it would be setting this data over and over. Anyway, this is my code so far:

```
 /////////////////////////////////SET TIME/DAYS///////////////////
    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    self.timeNow.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

    NSDate *lesson1Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"8:40"];
    NSDate *lesson2Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"9:35"];
    NSDate *recessStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"10:30"];
    NSDate *caregroupStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"10:50"];
    NSDate *lesson3Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"11:00"];
    NSDate *lesson4Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"11:55"];
    NSDate *lunchStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"12:50"];
    NSDate *lesson5Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"1:30"];
    NSDate *lesson6Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"2:20"];
    NSDate *endDay = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"3:10"];

    }
    //////////////////////////END SET TIMES/////////////////////////


- (void)updateTime {

    NSString *mondayDay = (@"Monday");
    NSString *tuesdayDay = (@"Tuesday");
    NSString *wednesdayDay = (@"Wednesday");
    NSString *thursdayDay = (@"Thursday");
    NSString *fridayDay = (@"Friday");

    [updateTimer invalidate];
    updateTimer = nil;

    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    self.timeNow.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                            target:self
                            selector:@selector(updateTime)
                            userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];

   ///////Check day/time & update lesson/////

    if (self.dayNow.text == mondayDay && self.timeNow.text == lesson1Start) {
        NSLog(@"");
    }
```

As you can see, I cannot use "lesson1Start" since it is not in `- (void)updateTime`.

Would it be fine if I did bundle it all noting that it would be setting this data over and over since it is placed in the timer.

PS: I am trying to check if when the lesson starts and if the time is when the lesson starts then the lesson would appear. In this case I just have `NSLog(@"")`.

Comment: Have you ever heard about instance variables?

Comment: You can't compare string using `==`. You need to use `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: I think it's hard to notice in output `NSLog(@"");`. It would better `NSLog(@"It's monday now. First lesson start");`

Comment: My code was a quick sketch to give you a better idea of what I was aiming for. The real problem here is me trying to create global variables.... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do as...
Lets consider your code is in class ClassRoom;

```
@interface ClassRoom 
{
NSArray *scheduleArray; //instance variable
}
```

you can create a `NSArray *scheduleArray;` for holding //you have to allocate and init it in implementation file

```
NSDate *lesson1Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"8:40"];
NSDate *lesson2Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"9:35"];
NSDate *recessStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"10:30"];
NSDate *caregroupStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"10:50"];
NSDate *lesson3Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"11:00"];
NSDate *lesson4Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"11:55"];
NSDate *lunchStart = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"12:50"];
NSDate *lesson5Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"1:30"];
NSDate *lesson6Start = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"2:20"];
NSDate *endDay = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"3:10"];
```

add all above dates in scheduleArray.(Hope you know how to add items in NSArray.)

Now you can write updateTime as

```
    - (void)updateTime {

        NSString *mondayDay = (@"Monday");
        NSString *tuesdayDay = (@"Tuesday");
        NSString *wednesdayDay = (@"Wednesday");
        NSString *thursdayDay = (@"Thursday");
        NSString *fridayDay = (@"Friday");

        [updateTimer invalidate];
        updateTimer = nil;

        currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        self.timeNow.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

        updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                target:self
                                selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];

       ///////Check day/time & update lesson/////

for(NSDate * date in scheduleArray){

  here you will get above saved dates use them to your need.
}

}
```

Hope it helps !